# Maximum key size in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'm completely new to using cassandra.. is there a maximum key size and would that ever impact performance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cassandra claims (apparently incorrectly!) that:

> The row key in a table is a string
>   with no size restrictions, although
>   typically 16 to 36 bytes long

See also:

http://cassandra-user-incubator-apache-org.3065146.n2.nabble.com/value-size-is-there-a-suggested-limit-td4959690.html which suggests that there is *some* limit.

Clearly, very large keys could have *some* network performance impact if they need to be sent over the Thrift RPC interface - and they would cost storage. I'd suggest you try a quick benchmark to see what impact it has for your data.

One way to deal with this might be to pre-hash your keys and just use the hash value as the key, though this won't suit all use cases.

Answer (score 15):

The key (and column names) must be under 64K bytes.

Routing is O(N) of the key size and querying and updating are O(N log N). In practice these factors are usually dwarfed by other overhead, but some users with very large "natural" keys use their hashes instead to cut down the size.

Comment: Can this be added to http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraLimitations or some other sensible place? - I haven't seen this documented anywhere...

Comment: The wiki is publicly editable. Just click Login to create an account.

Comment: Thanks - added info to http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#max_key_size and http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraLimitations